how can i change html input to change to decimal when pressing comma while typing
I have a number input. While typing on it, if you press dot ('.'), you change to decimal part. But if you press comma (','), nothing happens. I want it to also change to decimal typing, just like when you press dot.
Is it possible to do this?
It is hard for me to explain my problem, so; hard to search for a solution too.
Edit: i don't want to see a comma on the input, i just want to switch to the right side of the dot (i mean typing the decimal part) on the input by pressing the comma.

you can change the step of the input to be a decimal number to allow both dot and comma (at least in Chrome for me), the only problem is "e" is allowed but you can work around that. Check out the docs for more info

It's possible but if you use input element of type number it's a little difficult. So I used type text and made the action behavior as you want. I provide my code for it.


const numberInput = document.getElementById('number-input');

numberInput.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    if (event.key === ',') {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (!numberInput.value.includes('.')) {
            numberInput.value += '.';
        }

        numberInput.setSelectionRange(numberInput.value.length, numberInput.value.length);
    }
});

numberInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
    numberInput.value = numberInput.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');

    const parts = numberInput.value.split('.');
    if (parts.length > 2) {
        numberInput.value = parts[0] + '.' + parts[1];
    }
});
<input type="text" id="number-input" placeholder="Enter a number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="decimal">



